# How to inherit from models in Rails, where one type extends another without intertwining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord, associations

I'm aware of the number of posts on this, but still I can't figure out how to do this. I have a model "InspirationItem", which is basically a blog posts. Now I also want a second model, "Special". Specials are like inspiration items but they have extra properties, such as an "excerpt" and a "theme". So I want to extend the "InspirationPost" model.

I've tried to create a model "Post", which both "InspirationItem" and "Special" extend, but "InspirationItem" doesn't really add any properties to. Then, I create a "has_one" relation from InspirationItem/Special and try to use "delegate" to handle all logics in the "Post" model. However this does not work like I'd expect at all.

Here's some of my code. This would be my InspirationItem:

```
class InspirationItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :post, :as => :item

    delegate            :title, :title=,
                        :body, :body=,
                        :category_names, :category_names=,
                        :hide_from_overview, :hide_from_overview=,
                        :to => :post, :allow_nil => true

end
```

And this is a short version of post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :title, :body, :embed, :hide_from_overview, :visual, :thumbnail, :category_names
    # All sorts of logics
end
```

What's important is that I don't want InspirationItem.all to return Specials too, that's why I use the Post model. I also want regular error handling to work for all models. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into Single Table Inheritance?  This might make more sense than trying to include the Post models in your InspirationItem through a relationship.

Comment: Yes I have, but Special has quite a few more attributes than Inspiration, so I thought that I'd be ugly to have so many empty columns for Inspiration instances.

Comment: Ok I ended up following your suggestion. Instead of creating a relation both now use the posts table.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evils" - Donald Knuth.  Unless empty columns are an issue for you, select a set of models that are easy to code to.  If in the long term a sparse database becomes an issue, you can always try to mollify that in the database.

Comment: Such wishdom;) I've build it like this, works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an ActiveRecord subclass of a model, but don't want the parent to search any of the children, then something like this should work (I'll use your `InspirationItem` class):

```
class InspirationItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.descendants
    super.reject {|klass| klass == Special}
  end
end

class Special < InspirationItem
end
```

This is a bit hacky, but will force ActiveRecord to only return InspirationItems when you search `InspirationItem.all`. And this shouldn't affect validations.

EDIT: Re: What the tables would look like for this.

```
create_table :inspiration_items do |t|
  t.string :type # needed for the Single Table Inheritance mechanism
  # whatever other columns you need for InspirationItems
end
```

Comment: Looks good, what would my tables look like in this situation?

Comment: I just updated my answer with what the table would look like for the InspirationItems class. Since Special would be a subclass of InspirationItem, they would use the same database table.

Comment: This is great, thanks. Instead of the self.desendants magic I've still created a resource Post, and both InprirationItem and Special inherit from it. That way, I can always select Post.all, which is a scenario that will become relevant in the future.

Comment: Yeah, it is magic and I'm glad you were able to avoid it. Using a common superclass for both is definitely a better idea.